# Changing styles.xml file requires me to rebuild my project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I have an android project, when I change my **styles.xml** file in Android Studio I need to rebuild my project every time.

If I do not rebuild it, android studio deploys my app without **visual changes**.

Is this a correct behaviour or there is some trick that I can use?

Because rebuilding every time I change background colour of an item during theme tweaking is kinda slow and inefficient.

**UPDATED:**

My original styles.xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.NoTitleMine" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.MyDarkMaterialDesignBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
        <!--button active style as well as edit text color (selected), also underline color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redesign_highlight_color</item>
        <!--edit text activate, spinner click color-->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/redesign_highlight_color</item>
        <!--form background color-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/redesign_background</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/redesign_background</item>
        <item name="disabledMaterialButtonColor">@color/redesign_disabled_button</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MaterialButton</item>
        <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/DarkSpinnerStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyDarkMaterialDesign" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!--button active style as well as edit text color (selected), also underline color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redesign_highlight_color</item>
        <!--edit text activate, spinner click color-->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/redesign_highlight_color</item>
        <!--form background color-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/redesign_background</item>
        <item name="disabledMaterialButtonColor">@color/redesign_disabled_button</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MaterialButton</item>
        <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/DarkSpinnerStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkSpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/redesign_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/material_button_style_selector</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Padding" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayFilledPadding</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyThemeOverlayFilledPadding">
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_padding</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_padding" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
        <!-- left and right padding -->
        <item name="android:paddingStart" ns2:ignore="NewApi">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd" ns2:ignore="NewApi">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>

        <!-- top and bottom padding -->
        <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    </style>



    <style name="DesignAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/designGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/designGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorForegroundInverse">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>+
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/DesignEditText</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/MainThemeSpinner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DesignEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/designGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/designBrightGreyTextColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DesignTextViewBright" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designWhiteColor</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DesignTextViewPale" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designPaleColor</item>
    </style>



    <style name="DesignButtonNoBorder" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_button_noborder</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designWhiteColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainThemeSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainThemeSpinnerUnderlined" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/holoSpinner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="holoSpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DesignButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/round_button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designWhiteColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RedAppLightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/redColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DesignAppLightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/DesignEditTextLight</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/designColorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DesignEditTextLight" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
    </style>



    <style name="DesignAppBlackColorTabLightTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/designColorPrimaryGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextApearance</item>

    </style>

    <style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DesignAppLightTheme.NoTitleMine" parent="DesignAppLightTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DesignAppTheme.NoTitleMine" parent="DesignAppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/DesignButtonNoBorder</item>
    </style>


    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <!--buttons color-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
        <!--title and message color-->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <!--dialog background-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_dialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/designColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/designColorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try to `restart` or `clear cache and restart` Android Studio

Comment: tried, but no hope :(

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no need to rebuilt project every time if you make changes into **style.xml** file.

So, for this problem try either of these steps.

1) Build-> 1)Clean Project
           2)Rebuild project

now make change and check without doing rebuilt project and another thing you can do is

2)Files-> Invalidate caches/restart.

I think either of these will help you.

Comment: tried, but still i need at least run Clean Project after every styles.xml change in order to make it display my changes.

Comment: it's too long, cannot post it here :(  
P.S. I will update my original post

Comment: How much line are there? or else can you click snapshot of you code and post here so that at least some lines of your code can be recognise and may be it will help to reach at exact solution . if possible then please add no matter with no. of lines of code

Comment: added to the post

Comment: By the way I am changing background color of a spinner:

<style name="DarkSpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/redesign_background</item>
    </style>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203023/discussion-between-twisha-kotecha-and-sergei-yendiyarov).

Answer (score 0):

**Try to invalidate cache and restart.**

if it doest work you should **manually delete all build**
 folders from your project. delete from each module.